# Pushing Additional Git Remote Information

Tags: git

Is it possible to push information about additional remotes to a single remote? For example if we have a fork of a project that we develop on would it be possible to have it such that when a new user checks out our fork it already contains the upstream remote?

Comment: I don't think so. You could commit a script file which adds the additional remotes. New users would then need to run this script after cloning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do this automatically.  Git remote information is generally stored in the configuration file, and Git's security model doesn't permit untrusted configuration because there are numerous ways doing so can cause arbitrary code execution.

As knittl suggested, you can add a script into your codebase or as part of your build system that does this, which is the recommended way to go about adjusting Git configuration settings.  Note that you may also want to consider some way to disable this, since some people may want different remote names.